# How to access images from another location for create react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

How would I access images from another location in my computer other than my working directory while using Create React App. I am not sure whether I will have to eject or not, but the main issue is I uploaded all the images (thousands) which are dynamic based on recording to the public folder. However this is causing a reload of the the browser continually. I don't know how to turn off the hot reload module. Not sure what the best option is. The issue it is thousands of images that is being stored in the public folder which is causing the browser to refresh over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Images outside your static directory won't be available directly through the HTTP server by design.  You have to have the server handle acquiring these files for you.

I have done this by using the Node.JS FileSystem API to grab the image file.  Then I convert the image to a Data URI using a module like [datauri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datauri) and use an API to send the Data URI string to the client.  Then the client can place the image's Data URI in an IMG or CANVAS tag.

For the API I've used this pattern with an Express route, through Socket.IO and via a GraphQL query using [apollo-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server) and [apollo-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-react).

Comment: So what your saying is I don't have to store the image anywhere in my directory?

Comment: i created a symbolic link from my public folder to the external folder to get the images

Comment: Using a symbolic link will make it appear to the HTTP server that the images are in the folder so this is a fine solution, as long as you know the files will always be in that directory.  In my case, I don't know where the files will be until a request is made so it's not as easy.